# I have a title like Virtual Team Resources then i need its short code like VTR

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a title like Virtual Team Resources then i need its short code like VTR
 If Title Virtual Team then ShortCOde will be VTE
 i have implement this but still some issues like
 if user enter title  Virtual T then short code will ?

My Code------

```
function EnterShortCode() {
           debugger
           var ProjectShortCode = "";
           var Arr = $("#txtProjectTitle").val().rtrim().split(" ");
           for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
               if (Arr[i] != "" && Arr[i] != null) {
                   ProjectShortCode += Arr[i].substring(0, 1);
                   if (i == Arr.length - 1) {
                       if (ProjectShortCode.length == 1) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 3) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 3);
                           }
                       }
                       else if (ProjectShortCode.length == 2) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 2) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 2)
                           }

                       }

                   }
               }
           }

           ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode.toUpperCase();
           alert(ProjectShortCode);
       }
```

Comment: You want to take a string and make a new string containing characters after spaces or the beginning of the first string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have modified your function slightly that may help you

```
 function EnterShortCode() {
     var ProjectShortCode = "";
           var Arr = rtrim($("#txtProjectTitle").val()).split(" ");
    if (Arr.length>2)
    {        
    for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
               if (Arr[i] != "" && Arr[i] != null) {
                   ProjectShortCode += Arr[i].substring(0, 1);
                   if (i == Arr.length - 1) {
                       if (ProjectShortCode.length == 1) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 3) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 3);
                           }
                       }
                       else if (ProjectShortCode.length == 2) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 2) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 2)
                           }

                       }

                   }
               }
           }
         }
       else
       {
          for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
               if (Arr[i] != "" && Arr[i] != null) {
                             if(i==0 && Arr.length==2)
              {              
                 ProjectShortCode += Arr[i].substring(0, 2);
              }
                           else if(i==0 && Arr.length==1)
                           {
                               ProjectShortCode += Arr[i].substring(0, 3);
                           }
              else
              {
                     ProjectShortCode += Arr[i].substring(0, 1);
              }   

                   if (i == Arr.length) {
                       if (ProjectShortCode.length == 1) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 3) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 3);
                           }
                       }
                       else if (ProjectShortCode.length == 2) {
                           if (Arr[i] < 2) {

                           }
                           else {
                               ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode + Arr[i].substring(1, 2)
                           }

                       }

                   }
               }
           }                         
       }
           ProjectShortCode = ProjectShortCode.toUpperCase();
           alert(ProjectShortCode);
    }
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spSjT/3/)